# Implement the dog bash utility

Tags: code-golf, string, file-system

`dog` is a command-line utility that takes in an arbitrary number of arguments,
the first of which is the text to be written and the others are arbitrarily many files.

The `dog` utility will split the text in equal portions over these files. If there is a remainder `n`, the first `n` files get an additional byte

`dog` is the opposite of `cat`, as such, forall `x`, the following should hold.

```
$> dog x a.txt b.txt ...
$> cat a.txt b.txt ...
x$>
```

Where `...` indicates arbitrarily many files.

An example (12 bytes, 3 files, can be split evenly):

```
$> ./dog.py "Dogs vs Cats" a.txt b.txt c.txt
$> cat a.txt
Dogs$> cat b.txt
 vs $> cat c.txt
Cats$> cat a.txt b.txt c.txt
Dogs vs Cats$>
```

An example with remainder (13 bytes, 5 files, remainder 3):

```
9$>./dog.py "0123456789abc" a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt e.txt
$> cat a.txt
012$> cat b.txt
345$> cat c.txt
678$> cat d.txt
9a$> cat e.txt
bc$> cat a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt e.txt
0123456789abc$>
```

Comment: It's implied, but just to double check: 1) Do the arguments have to come in via command line? 2) Do we always have to output to files?

Comment: @Sp3000 yes, to 1 and 2

Comment: It would be more "unixy" for the input string to come from STDIN.  But that's your call...

Comment: @DigitalTrauma there's already an answer, I would feel bad for invalidating it by a rule change

Comment: I've been learning about some oddly-named UNIX utilities from this site lately (tac, dog, ...).

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos They are non-existent, they are just word-puns over the cat util

Comment: Yeah, I know, but they're still weird, and I wouldn't be surprised if someone has actually named tools like that before.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos and Caridorc: [`tac` is real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tac_(Unix)).

Comment: @DLosc funny, `tac` is an x-ray medical exam in Italian. I think it is just a coincidence though

Comment: @Caridorc Apparently the 'tac' scan is the language word order for a 'cat' scan in English (which is a special type of X-ray scan).  The Xray (or at least what Americans would consider an X-ray - where you put up a static flat image) is raggi X. Oh, the joys that the 'other languages' sidebar on Wikipedia can bring.

Comment: I like the idea of ***equal portions over these files*** with at least 1 byte len as maximum difference!

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - 12 bytes

```
.wMC,cl.zz.z
```

Uses builtin split function and then uses splat-map on the write function. Doesn't work online.

Answer (score 2):

## Python - 181 bytes

```
import sys
a=sys.argv
l=len
d=a[2:]
s=a[1]
n,r=divmod(l(s),l(d))
p=0
for i in range(l(d)):
    with open(d[i],'w') as f:
        o=n+int(i<=n)
        f.write(s[p:p+o])
        p+=o
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 107 bytes

The golfed code:

```
for($i=1;++$i<$argc;fputs(fopen($argv[$i],w),substr($s=$argv[1],($i-2)*$l=ceil(strlen($s)/($argc-2)),$l)));
```

The detailed code:

```
$len = ceil(strlen($argv[1])/($argc - 2));
for ($i = 2; $i < $argc; $i ++) {
    $fh = fopen($argv[$i], 'w');
    fputs($fh, substr($argv[1], ($i - 2) * $len, $len));
    fclose($fh);          // omitted in the golfed version
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Pure bash: 97

```
s=$1;shift;for((l=${#s}/$#,m=${#s}-l*$#,i=1;i<=$#;p+=q,i++)){
printf "${s:p:q=i>m?l:l+1}">${!i};}
```

As a function: (`p=` is only required for second run)

```
dog() { p=
    s=$1;shift;for((l=${#s}/$#,m=${#s}-l*$#,i=1;i<=$#;p+=q,i++)){
    printf "${s:p:q=i>m?l:l+1}">${!i};}
}
```

Tests

```
$> rm *
$> dog "Dogs vs Cats" a.txt b.txt c.txt
$> ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 4 May 13 22:09 a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 4 May 13 22:09 b.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 4 May 13 22:09 c.txt
$> cat {a,b,c}.txt;echo
Dogs vs Cats
$>
```

All files is 4 byte len and concatenated in right order, contain *"Dogs vs Cats"*.

```
$> rm *
$> dog "$(printf "%s" {0..9} {a..c})" {a..e}.txt 
$> ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 3 May 13 22:09 a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 3 May 13 22:09 b.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 3 May 13 22:09 c.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2 May 13 22:09 d.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2 May 13 22:09 e.txt
$> cat *;echo
0123456789abc
$>
```

Firsts files is 3 byte len and last only 2, concatenated by alphabetic order, contain *"0123456789abc"*.

#### Explanation (ungolfing):

If you hit: `declare -f dog`, [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) will answer:

```
$> declare -f dog
dog () 
{ 
    p=;
    s=$1;
    shift;
    for ((l=${#s}/$#,m=${#s}-l*$#,i=1; i<=$#; p+=q,i++))
    do
        printf "${s:p:q=i>m?l:l+1}" > ${!i};
    done
}
```

This could be written:

```
dog2 () 
{ 
    position=0;
    string=$1;
    shift;
    partLen=$((${#string}/$#));
    oneMore=$((${#string}-partLen*$#));
    for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++))
    do
        if ((i<=oneMore)); then
            partQuant=$((partLen+1));
        else
            partQuant=$partLen;
        fi;
        printf "${string:position:partQuant}" > ${!i};
        ((position+=partQuant));
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>93</s> 87 bytes

Full program using command line arguments.

If I could use `s.slice!` to mutate the string, I'd do that instead of needing to use `s[c..-1]`, but Ruby doesn't let you mutate the strings from argv without duplicating them first

```
s,*t=$*
d,r=s.size.divmod t.size
t.map{|e|open(e,?w)<<s[0,c=(0>r-=1)?d:d+1];s=s[c..-1]}
```